# Is there a way that we can avoid multiple token generations for a single user if he/she try to login on different browsers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am using django-rest-framework-jwt in my backend and calling API's from Angular Project.
When user try to login on multiple Browsers, each time a new token is generated for the user on new browser. And every token is valid.
What I want is that when user is already logged in in one browser and he/she tries to login on second different browser the previous token for first browser should be invalidated.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure if you can achieve this. The reason being the tokens are not tied to users.

Comment: Also, since you're using JWT it's implict that your services are stateless. You're not maintaining sessions anywhere. So, you can't invalidate access tokens.

Comment: What you can do at the max here is suitably reduce the lifetime of your `jwt` tokens to assure better security.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple word, **NO**, you can't just avoid generating tokens unless you made a little twist in django-rest-framework-jwt module. But that's not pure jwt anymore.

> JWT stands for JSON Web Tokens and it's a mechanism for exchanging data between computer systems that happens to be convenient for generating authorization headers that can be used to implement statless auth in web apps.

SO

> stateless means that you don't track user tokens, You just verify them. If token is valid and the payload is valid, then OK. It doesn't care how many tokens are generated and it doesn't care that they are related to one user. The token is created  based on timestamp and will be verified compared to lifetime and timestamp of it.

It means that django rest jwt module, will create a token based on current timestamp of system, whenever user request for it.

> Remember you can't delete a jwt token. Because it's not stored in database. So if your token is spoofed, that's it. You can't do anything with it, unless life cycle of the token ends and token expire.

If you want to track these tokens and be able to control them and for example don't create redundant tokens for a user as you asked:

- consider changing to another token based authentication that stores token in database so you could track it.
- change jwt system to what is suitable for you (I did it before). For example add a lookup id in database and check tokens by that bounded to each user. I know it's not jwt anymore, But you can still use some goodies of it. Like don't hit database on not valid jwt tokens and store some payload in it, if verified don't hit database for that info. Like permissions and ...